# Prepare MySQL for big UPDATE query on production server

Tags: mysql, update, rollback

Surprisingly I have not found anything relevant on this subject.

What are best practices to prepare production MySQL server for a big update query? The question is broad but I'd like to know details for a typical setup:

- MySQL 5.6
- 80/20 read/write workflow ratio
- Only InnoDB
- Replication Master
- Query Cache enabled
- Data fits entirely into memory buffer pool with some spare room left
- Healthy HDD drives on hardware RAID-1
- Millions of rows in the update query
- The query only covers single table (1 primary key - INT)

And the questions:

- What to look for?
- What mysql configuration parameters will be most relevant for the process to go quickly and smoothly?
- Is it worth splitting the update into multiple batches?

Answer (score 2):

The Query cache is a hindrance.  (In general, it should be OFF for production systems.)  All entries in the QC for that table will be purged by the Update.

Millions of rows -- all of the table?  A small fraction of a billion row table, but no good index?  What?

Let's dissect the query...

Scan through the entire table.  This takes time for the following reasons:

- Read the blocks
- Write the "undo" records to disk (in case of `ROLLBACK` or crash)
- Write the blocks back to disk
- Toss the undo blocks

The size of "undo" may necessitate a less efficient method, adding to the overall time.

The affected rows will be locked; well you may as well plan on the 'entire' table being blocked from other usage.

Batching...

- Avoids blocking as long
- Probably takes longer overall
- Complexity in the code
- Not atomic (if that matters)

Why do you need to do such a big Update?  Perhaps the column you are changing should be in a separate, parallel, table to avoid this much impact?  Or 'computed' by subsequent `SELECTs`?

Config changes?  Assuming the innodb_buffer_pool_is big enough, nothing useful to do.

For chunking, see [advice on chunking](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) -- that talks about deleting, but can be adapted to updating.

Comment: Thanks for your time looking at this. I really wanted to find out best general practice but in my specific case: 99.9% rows of the table hold the same default application settings in a TEXT field (don't ask me why). I was going to null these defaults and reduce size of the entire database by over 80%. QC works well so far - most frequently updated tables are always queried with SQL_NO_CACHE flag.

Comment: A one time fix?  And it does not matter how long it takes?  And you can stop/restart as needed?  Then chunking, preferably on the `PRIMARY KEY` sounds good.  But...  Did QC save 80% without further action?  If so, good; proceed.  (This last question relates to InnoDB doing less that a perfect job of freeing up blocks from updates/deletes.)

Comment: If your table is in ibdata1, then the free blocks will be returned to the general free space.  If you had file_per_table, the free blocks will be in the free space for that one table.  In either case, the blocks will not be returned to the OS.  If you expect the table(s) to continue to grow, fine.  If you are desperate for disk space, then trouble.

Comment: Thanks! Batching helped a lot in the end the operation went well, only had to increase smaller buffer pool on the replica as it could not keep after the initial chunks. Had innodb_file_per_table=1 so simple optimize restored the space.